# Any way to make a grid style list in twig templates?

Tags: html, wordpress, grid, twig

I'm trying to make a 3x3 grid of a template made in twig for WordPress, I'm using a `for` to show a media player for every episode that I currently have added but it's being shown only in a list format.

Current code:

```
{% for episode in podcast.episodes({ orderby: "publicationDate", order: "DESC", limit: 200 }) %}
    <div class="width">
        {{ episode.player }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Current outcome:**

[image: this is what i currently have]

**Desired outcome:**

[image: this is how i want it to be]

This is how to looks after applying your code, im guessing chapter 4 looks like that because it does not have a subtitle.
[image: after edits]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this template doesn't have CSS classes for grids already - you will need to add your own CSS code.

To get a 3 column grid, you can use something like this:

```css
.movie-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

I've also added a `grid-gap` for spacing.

And then modify your template like so:

```
<div class="movie-grid">
{% for episode in podcast.episodes({ orderby: "publicationDate", order: "DESC", limit: 200 }) %}
    <div class="width">
        {{ episode.player }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Change grid-gap to add more space.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i found it later, thats why i deleted the comment. Thanks again! and sorry to bother.